# jQuery on-change using multiple selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best way to refactor the following code to avoid duplication?

```
    // JQuery FORM Functions
$(document).on('change','.submittable',function(){
     //save current input field into hidden input 'focus_field' if it exists
        if($('input#focus_field').length){
            var $focus_field = $(this).attr('id')
            $('input#focus_field').val($focus_field)
        }
    $('input[type=submit]').click();
    return false;
});


$(document).on('change','.submittable_wait',function(){
    $('#please_wait').show();
    $('input[type=submit]').click();
    return false;
});


$(document).on('change','.submittable_wait_bar',function(){
    $('#ajax_working').show();
    $('input[type=submit]').click();
    return false;
});

$(document).on('change','.submittable_wait_bar_single',function(){
    $('#ajax_working').show();
    $( this ).closest("form").submit();
    return false;
});

// nested_form - fields added
$(document).on('nested:fieldAdded', function(event) {
    $('#ajax_working').show();
    $('#reload_form').val('true');
    $('input[type=submit].btn-primary').click()
});

// nested_form - fields removed
$(document).on('nested:fieldRemoved', function(event) {
    $('#please_wait').show();
    $('#reload_form').val('true');
    $('input[type=submit].btn-primary').click()
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some general points:

- Watch your indentation
- Watch your whitespace
- An id is unique on a page - there is no benefit to 'element#id' vs '#id' as a selector
- It is usually better to store references to elements that don't get removed

Let's apply some of these on the change handler to store the focus field. Here's what we're starting with:

```
$(document).on('change','.submittable',function(){
    if($('input#focus_field').length){
        var $focus_field = $(this).attr('id')
        $('input#focus_field').val($focus_field)
    }
    $('input[type=submit]').click();
    return false;
});
```

We don't want to search the DOM for the element every time (*unless it can be added/removed*) so let's pull it out:

```
var $focusField = $('#focus_field');
```

Notice that I've simplified the selector to just the Id. Now we can use our knowledge of jQuery to simplify the next bit of the function.

```
$(document).on('change', '.submittable', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $focusField.val(this.id);
     $('input[type=submit]').click();
}
```

The reason this works is that selecting a set of elements that don't exist in the DOM returns an empty jQuery array which is more than happy to be chained - it just won't do anything. I've also modified your `return false` to use the recommended `preventDefault` function on the `event` object.

If you want you can pull out common functionality into separate functions. For example:

```
var showAndReload = function (selector) {
    $(selector).show();
    $('#reload_form').val('true');
    $('input[type=submit].btn-primary').click()
};

// nested_form - fields added
$document.on('nested:fieldAdded', function() {
    showAndReload('#ajax_working')
});

// nested_form - fields removed
$document.on('nested:fieldRemoved', function() {
    showAndReload('#please_wait');
});
```

I'm not really sure it adds much though.

Comment: As an addition, here is an explanation of the difference between ```return false```and ```event.preventDefault()```: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false